# How to get a static tmap with shiny as show in rstudio?

Tags: r, shiny, tmap

I'm learning shiny and tmap.
I'm able to get the map I want on Rstudio (a static tmap).
But when I try a similar tmap code with shiny, I always get an interactive map.

From this reprex, I try to get the same map I get on Rstudio.
I try to add `tmap_mode("plot")` after the `renderTmap`, but it doesn't work.

[image: World Map]

My question look too simple... but can't find the answer!
Thank for your help.

```
library(shiny)

data(World)
world_vars <- setdiff(names(World), c("iso_a3", "name", "sovereignt", "geometry"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  tmapOutput("map"),
  selectInput("var", "Variable", world_vars)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderTmap({
    tmap_mode("plot")
    tm_shape(World) +
      tm_polygons(world_vars[1], zindex = 401)
  })
}   

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

`tmap_mode()` doesn't work inside Shiny for me either, but there's actually a very easy alternative: instead of `tmapOutput` and `renderTmap` for interactive maps, you can just use `plotOutput` and `renderPlot`.

So the following code creates the exact map from your image and lets the user select a variable to plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(tmap)

data(World)
world_vars <- setdiff(names(World), c("iso_a3", "name", "sovereignt", "geometry"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("map"),
  selectInput("var", "Variable", world_vars)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    tm_shape(World) +
      tm_polygons(input$var)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```